# Problem to create EntityManager on Javafx + Maven Project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, javafx, module-info

I'm creating a Maven project with JavaFX and Hibernate and I am getting the following error when I try to create an EntityManager.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at org.jboss.logging@3.4.2.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2562)
at org.jboss.logging@3.4.2.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530)
at org.jboss.logging@3.4.2.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.4.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.4.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.4.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.<clinit>(PersistenceXmlParser.java:54)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.4.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.4.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.4.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at org.example/org.example.Apps.main(Apps.java:9)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 14 more

it's my MainClass

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Apps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pessoaPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

module-info.java

```
module org.example {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    opens org.example to javafx.fxml;

    exports org.example;
}
```

persistense.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="pessoaPU"
                      transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/person?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>lalalala</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.4.Final</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.49</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfbsw.png)

Comment: Looks like `requires java.sql` is missing

Comment: thanks!!! it worked, but i add more requires than java.sql: ´requires net.bytebuddy;
    requires com.fasterxml.classmate;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    opens org.example to javafx.fxml´